# Get the current value of MultiFactorAuthAge for an AWS user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

One can write a AWS policy which requires a recent MFA authentication by checking the value of *MultiFactorAuthAge*. Such a process is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21917197/1039462).

My question is, is it possible to retrieve that *MultiFactorAuthAge* value for some (or all) users with a call to the AWS API?