# Get MFA API credentials for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Let's say I have set up an IAM policy to enforce multi-factor authentication (MFA) for all AWS API requests (such as the one described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70792832/2800876).  I can get and use temporary credentials via `sts get-session-token` with the following code:

```
# Get the serial number of your MFA device
aws --profile <PROFILE_NAME> iam list-mfa-devices --user-name <IAM_USER_NAME>

# Get temporary API keys that will pass MFA verification
aws --profile <PROFILE_NAME> sts get-session-token --serial-number <MFA_SERIAL_NUMBER> --token-code <MFA_TOKEN>

# Export the temporary credentials for use in subsequent calls
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<KEY>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<SECRET>
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=<SESSION_TOKEN>
```

However, this code requires several steps and only works for the terminal window I do it in.  How do I make this work with a single command that saves the credentials until they expire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a command line tool called `iam-mfa` that will do this for you: https://github.com/zagaran/iam-mfa.  (Disclaimer: I am the primary author of the tool.)

The key is to use named profiles.  One profile (the source_profile) will hold the credentials that you use to call `sts get-session-token`.  The other profile (the dest_profile) will be where you save the session token you get from sts, and is the profile you use to do all subsequent API calls.

You can install it with `pip install iam-mfa`.

You can then call it with:

```
iam-mfa <source_profile> <dest_profile> <iam_username>
```

When you run the script, it will prompt you for an MFA code.